# How does "import * as bootstrap from '../node_modules/bootstrap' work?

Tags: javascript, npm, javascript-import

Near the top of my `app.js` file, I have the line

```
import * as bootstrap from '../../node_modules/bootstrap';
```

If I `console.log(bootstrap)` on the next line, then I can see that the `bootstrap` variable does indeed hold a bootstrap-looking object with all the properties I'd expect.

The question is though, how does this work, because `node_modules\bootstrap` is just a directory

```
|- node_modules
    |-> bootstrap
        |-> dist [dir]
        |-> js [dir]
        |-> scss [dir]
        |-> LICENCE [txt file]
        |-> package.json
        |-> README.md
```

So how exactly does it work out what needs to be imported into the `bootstrap` variable?

It's more curiosity as to how this works really, because it does work correctly.

*EDIT: (directory structure was edited since original post)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How `import` looks for a particular file depends on the environment. But if you use node or a common bundler like webpack, rollup, or vite, then those use the `package.json` file in the module that you `import`/`require` to figure out which file is the entry point.

In the case of bootstrap, you have the following lines in [`package.json`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/913efd78c63990eecf27a4b755b4221a266ff3b0/package.json#L37)

```
  "main": "dist/js/bootstrap.js",
  "module": "dist/js/bootstrap.esm.js",
```

(These lines might vary, I have taken those from GitHub)

This means that it will load the file listed at `main` in case `require('boostrap')` is used or at `module` if you do `import * as bootstrap from 'boostrap'`. In those files, you could see what is exported.

There could even be more entires that e.g. differentiate between `node` and `browser` and could have additional aliases.

Comment: You're right.  I'm using vite.  It did cross my mind at some point whether the `package.json` was being read while compiling the assets but I've never heard of it working that way before, so wanted to ask the question in a general context to see what people came up with.

Answer (score -1):

`import * as bootstrap ...` is taking all the exported modules and putting them in `bootstrap` object

If you open `./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js`, you'd find the `export {some_func, some_func_2}` which is exporting the intended objects and function.

Comment: Thanks.  You are correct.  But I did already work out that it was reading one of the files in the `/dist` directory.  The point of the question is how does it know which one to load, and that is not a question you answered in this reply.